# Looks like my each loop is looping more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

The code below should read the stored ID's from a cookie (saved in a cookie so if you reload the page it will have your saved sessions stored in a cookie to read next time), look up the DIV linked to that ID, and append rows to a table with the title, date, code and time of the session that ID is for, however when there is multiple dates linked to a single session DIV, it should create a row for each, which It seems to be doing correctly.

BUT, it seems the each loop at `sessDateVar.each(function( i, val )` is running twice? When I `console.log` the current session code and date for the row that is being appended in the while loop, as well as the value of `i` it seems to repeat? I cant seem to figure this out.

The code is a little messy right now, sorry! If I left anything out, please let me know!

**Contents of my console when the while loop runs**

```
(index):1994 Wrote a row for session A6 on date Wednesday, May 18, 2016
(index):1995 0
(index):1994 Wrote a row for session D6 on date Thursday, May 19, 2016
(index):1995 1
(index):1994 Wrote a row for session A6 on date Wednesday, May 18, 2016
(index):1995 0
(index):1994 Wrote a row for session D6 on date Thursday, May 19, 2016
(index):1995 1
(index):1994 Wrote a row for session C6 on date Wednesday, May 18, 2016
(index):1995 0
(index):1994 Wrote a row for session F6 on date Thursday, May 19, 2016
(index):1995 1
(index):1994 Wrote a row for session C6 on date Wednesday, May 18, 2016
(index):1995 0
(index):1994 Wrote a row for session F6 on date Thursday, May 19, 2016
(index):1995 1
```

**The Code**

```
 function writeTable() {
  if (checkCookie() === false) {
    $('#table-container').append('<table class="tg" id="session-table">\n<thead>\n<tr>\n<th class="tg-yw4l">Session</th>\n<th class="tg-yw4l">Date</th>\n<th class="tg-yw4l">Time</th>\n<th class="tg-yw4l"></th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n</tbody>\n</table>');
    $('.table-container-export').append('<table class="tg" cellpadding="10" id="session-table-export">\n<thead>\n<tr>\n<th class="tg-title">Session</th>\n<th class="tg-info">Date</th>\n<th class="tg-info">Time</th>\n<th class="tg-info">Session Code</th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n</tbody>\n</table>');
  } else if (checkCookie() === true) {
    var askToLoad = confirm('You have saved sessions in your browser, would you like to load those sessions?');
    if (askToLoad === true) {

      $('#table-container').append('<table class="tg" id="session-table">\n<thead>\n<tr>\n<th class="tg-yw4l">Session</th>\n<th class="tg-yw4l">Date</th>\n<th class="tg-yw4l">Time</th>\n<th class="tg-yw4l"></th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n</tbody>\n</table>');
      $('.table-container-export').append('<table class="tg" cellpadding="10" id="session-table-export">\n<thead>\n<tr>\n<th class="tg-title">Session</th>\n<th class="tg-info">Date</th>\n<th class="tg-info">Time</th>\n<th class="tg-info">Session Code</th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n</tbody>\n</table>');
      var tableDataUnparsed = Cookies.get('session-table');
      var tableDataExportUnparsed = Cookies.get('session-table-export');
      var tableDataParsed = JSON.parse(tableDataUnparsed);
      var tableDataExportParsed = JSON.parse(tableDataExportUnparsed);
      var tableDataExport = tableDataExportParsed;

      $.each(tableDataExportParsed, function( i, val ){
        var sessID = val;
        var sessionToFind = $(sessID);
        var sessTitle = sessionToFind.find('.title').html();
        var sessDateVar = sessionToFind.find('.date');
          if (sessDateVar.size() > 1) {
            var sessDates = [];
            sessDateVar.each(function() {
              sessDates.push($.trim($(this).html()));
            });
          } else {
            var sessDate = $.trim(sessionToFind.find('.date').html());
            var sessDates = false;
          }
        var sessTimeVar = sessionToFind.find('.time');
          if (sessTimeVar.size() > 1) {
            var sessTimes = [];
            sessTimeVar.each(function() {
              sessTimes.push($.trim($(this).html()));
            });
          } else {
            var sessTime = $.trim(sessionToFind.find('.time').html());
          }
        var sessCodeVar = sessionToFind.find('.code');
          if (sessCodeVar.size() > 1) {
            var sessCodes = [];
            sessCodeVar.each(function() {
              sessCodes.push($.trim($(this).html()));
            });
          } else {
            var sessCode = $.trim(sessionToFind.find('.code').html());
          }


        if (sessDates === false) {
          $('#session-table-export').append('<tr data-sessionID=' + sessID + '>\n<td width="210px" style="width:210px" class="tg-title" ><span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;"> ' + sessTitle + '</span></td>\n<td width="100px" style="width:100px" class="tg-info" > ' + sessDate + '</td>\n<td width="100px" style="width:100px" class="tg-info"> ' + sessTime + '</td>\n<td width="50px" style="width:50px" class="tg-sessioncode">' + sessCode + '</td>\n</tr>\n');
        } else {
          sessDateVar.each(function( i, val ){
            $('#session-table-export').append('<tr data-sessionID=' + sessID + '>\n<td width="210px" style="width:210px" class="tg-title" ><span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">' + sessTitle + '</span></td>\n<td width="100px" style="width:100px" class="tg-info" > ' + sessDates[i] + '</td>\n<td width="100px" style="width:100px" class="tg-info">' + sessTimes[i] + '</td>\n<td  width="50px" style="width:50px" class="tg-sessioncode"><p>' + sessCodes[i] + '</p></td></tr>\n');      
          });

        }

      });

      loadedFromCookie = true;

    } else if (askToLoad === false) {
      Cookies.remove('session-table', {
        path: '/isotope'
      });
      Cookies.remove('session-table-export', {
        path: '/isotope'
      });
      $('#table-container').append('<table class="tg" id="session-table">\n<thead>\n<tr>\n<th class="tg-yw41">Session</th>\n<th class="tg-yw4l">Date</th>\n<th class="tg-yw4l">Time</th>\n<th class="tg-yw4l">\n</th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n</tbody>\n</table>');
      $('.table-container-export').append('<table class="tg" cellpadding="10" id="session-table-export">\n<thead>\n<tr>\n<th class="tg-title">Session</th>\n<th class="tg-info">Date</th>\n<th class="tg-info">Time</th>\n<th class="tg-info">Session Code</th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n</tbody>\n</table>');
    }
  }
};
writeTable();
```

**The loop in question**

```
        if (sessDates === false) {
          $('#session-table-export').append('<tr data-sessionID=' + sessID + '>\n<td width="210px" style="width:210px" class="tg-title" ><span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;"> ' + sessTitle + '</span></td>\n<td width="100px" style="width:100px" class="tg-info" > ' + sessDate + '</td>\n<td width="100px" style="width:100px" class="tg-info"> ' + sessTime + '</td>\n<td width="50px" style="width:50px" class="tg-sessioncode">' + sessCode + '</td>\n</tr>\n');
        } else {
          sessDateVar.each(function( i, val ){
            $('#session-table-export').append('<tr data-sessionID=' + sessID + '>\n<td width="210px" style="width:210px" class="tg-title" ><span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">' + sessTitle + '</span></td>\n<td width="100px" style="width:100px" class="tg-info" > ' + sessDates[i] + '</td>\n<td width="100px" style="width:100px" class="tg-info">' + sessTimes[i] + '</td>\n<td  width="50px" style="width:50px" class="tg-sessioncode"><p>' + sessCodes[i] + '</p></td></tr>\n');      
            console.log('Wrote a row for session ' + sessCodes[i] + ' on date ' + sessDates[i] + '');
            console.log(i);
          });

        }
```

Comment: Did you try verify sessDateVar content before loop??

Comment: I did, and really I am just using the .each() as an alternative to a while loop (so that it will only loop as many times as there is dates attached to that session). But even if I replace the .each() with a while loop I get the same problem.

Comment: Could you show me the content of sessDateVar

Comment: So say there was only 1 session id added to the cookie, the sessions DIV ont he page has two dates attached (tagges with date class). So after we call `var sessDateVar = sessionToFind.find('.date');` we would see that `sessDateVar` would be `['<span class="date">Wednesday, May 18, 2016</span>','<span class="date">Wednesday, May 19, 2016</span>']` so if we did an each on it, it would only run 2 loops, correct?

Comment: It´s correct, look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/4zunv5hm/

Comment: Try to do the same

Comment: So even when I change `sessDateVar.each(function( i, val )` to `$.each(sessDateVar, function( i, val )` It still loops once then again and stops.

Comment: Where did you trigger the function writeTable(); may be it this function is executing twice

Comment: It is called right after we declare the function and does not get called anywhere else.

Comment: Ok a saw your code well, the problem is because you are looping inside a loop, you are looping first tableDataExportParsed and inside you have sessDateVar loop, so for each tableDataExportParsed you have you loop again sessDateVar.

Comment: That was my original thought, but I cant think of an alternative to using a loop in a loop. The first loop goes over the IDs in the cookie, and the second loop inside is buried in an IF statement and loops when there are multiple dates attached to the session so it will append a row for each date. Thoughts?

Comment: Your code is a little bit confused, you only want to loop sessCodeVar one time?

Comment: Problem solved! This piece of code is part of a larger file that does other things that influence this code. I couldn't paste my whole file, so I pasted to parts that were relevant and tried to explain the other parts that may affect it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! This piece of code is part of a larger file that does other things that influence this code. I couldn't paste my whole file, so I pasted to parts that were relevant and tried to explain the other parts that may affect it.

Long story short, `tableDataExportParsed` was including duplicate IDs (when it stores the IDS in a cookie it saw multiple dates and included an ID for each) so the loop and the code was perfectly fine, it was that there indeed was a duplicate for it to loop over again. So the solution was to clean `tableDataExportParsed` so it didn't include duplicates. Clearly my brain was friend after writing all this yesterday and had that oversight.